Minimize $\mathrm{tr}((FK + G)^TQ(FK + G) + K^TRK)$ over block lower-triangular matrices $K$
I want to solve the minimization problem
$$
\inf_{K\in\mathcal{K}}\mathrm{tr}\left(\left((FK + G)^TQ(FK + G) + K^TRK\right)\Sigma\right)
$$
where $\mathcal{K}$ is the set of block lower triangular matrices, $R$ is symmetric positive definite and $Q$ and $\Sigma$ are symmetric positive semidefinite. Using the Schur complement I can write the problem as a semidefinite program as follows:
\begin{align}
\inf_{K\in\mathcal{K}}\mathrm{tr}\left(\left((FK + G)^TQ(FK + G) + K^TRK\right)\Sigma\right) &= \inf_{K\in\mathcal{K}}\mathrm{tr}\left(K^T(F^TQF + R)K\Sigma\right) + 2\mathrm{tr}\left(\Sigma G^TQFK\right)+\mathrm{const}\\
&=\inf_{K\in\mathcal{K}, X\in\mathbb{S}^n_+}\left\{\mathrm{tr}\left(X\right) + 2\mathrm{tr}\left(\Sigma G^TQFK\right)\vert X\succeq \Sigma^{1/2}K^T(F^TQF + R)K\Sigma^{1/2}\right\}\\
&= \inf_{K\in\mathcal{K}, X\in\mathbb{S}^n_+}\mathrm{tr}\left(X\right) + 2\mathrm{tr}\left(\Sigma G^TQFK\right)\quad\text{s.t.}\begin{pmatrix}
(F^TQF + R)^{-1} & K\Sigma^{1/2}\\\Sigma^{1/2}K^T & X\end{pmatrix}\succeq0
\end{align}
I can solve this problem numerically with an SDP solver (there I explicitly state which entries above the diagonal of $K$ should be zero). However, this seems a little overkill. is there a better way to do this?

Can you share the matrices in a form of csv file? I'd be happy to try something.
